# Automating workflows locally with branching logic

Tags: automation, workflow, scheduler, airflow, oozie

I've used Apache Oozie and Airflow to automate workflows in Hadoop clusters, which is easy to use for specifying branching logic.

I'm now finding myself needing the same framework to automate a simple pipeline locally, on a Linux box. This pipeline consists of Bash scripts, Python scripts, and branching & parallelization logic (which decides which and how many jobs to execute next based on the output from the previous); the output should be written to the local filesystem.

I'm trying to automate this with Oozie running locally. But I feel this might be overkill - is it? Do people actually use Oozie for simple automation tasks? Or are there better tools/frameworks for what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

Try out [Sparrow6](https://github.com/melezhik/Sparrow6) - language agnostic automation framework, that runs tasks - plugins written on many languages ( Perl, Python, Bash, Ruby, Powershell ). The high level DSL is Perl6, for example:

```
#!perl6

directory "foo/bar"; # create directory, this is a core plugin

bash "uptime"; # execute Bash scripts, this is a core plugin

task-run "custom task", "cool-task" # execute custom plugin, created by user
```

Now, when [create a plugin](https://github.com/melezhik/Sparrow6/blob/master/documentation/development.md) you can return a [state](https://github.com/melezhik/Sparrow6/blob/master/documentation/development.md#task-states) from it and handle this state inside DSL code:

```
my %state = task-run "get balance", "ATM", %( action => "get_balance" );

if %state<balance> > 0 {

  task-run "withdraw cash", "ATM", %(
    amount => %state<balance>
  )
}
```

Here is the idea of how you can implement pipelines/branches through plugins and states.

Answer (score 0):

Airflow is considered the better option. Airflow is a lot more user friendly and has a much larger user community. Airflow has a more intuitive web UI and is more versatile.

Airflow also is considered to have more effective branching.

You could [check this out](https://www.astronomer.io/guides/airflow-vs-oozie/) for further reading if you're still not convinced. Here are some [code examples](https://godaddy.github.io/2018/11/15/developer-view-oozie-vs-airflow/) too.